# How to number table rows serially in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have this HTLM and JQuery:

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Try to get tbody first with jquery children. works faster!
    var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');

    //Then if no tbody just select your table 
    var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');

    $('[name=row_no]').text();

    $('button').click(function() {

        var rows = $('[name=row_no]').val();

        // If rows are at maximum 10,
        if (!(rows > 10)) {
            // then add rows
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                table.append('<tr>\n\
      <td></td>\n\
      <td><input name="product_name[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
      <td><input name="qty[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
      <td><input name="price[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
      </tr>');
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Error: Too many rows!\n" +
                  "Maximum allowed: 10\n" +
                  "- Inserted: " + rows);
        }
    });
});
```

I have been able to generate td in the tbody

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <input name="row_no" type="number" placeholder="Type Your Number of row"  />
   <button>Add row</button>
   <table id="myTable">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th class="column-title">SN</th>
            <th class="column-title">Product name</th>
            <th class="column-title">Quantity</th>
            <th class="column-title">Price</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```

The value value of row_no determines number of td rows to be formed.

How do I generate serial number (SN) for the rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');
    var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');
    $('[name=row_no]').text();
    $('button').click(function() {
        var rows = $('[name=row_no]').val();
        var num_rows = $("#myTable tbody tr").length;
        if (rows < 11) {
            var sn;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                sn = num_rows + i;
                table.append(`<tr>
      <td>${sn}</td>
      <td><input name="product_name[]" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input name="qty[]" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input name="price[]" type="text"/></td>
      </tr>`);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Error: Too many rows!\n" +
                  "Maximum allowed: 10\n" +
                  "- Inserted: " + rows);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="row_no" type="number" placeholder="Type Your Number of row"  />
   <button>Add row</button>
   <table id="myTable">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th class="column-title">SN</th>
            <th class="column-title">Product name</th>
            <th class="column-title">Quantity</th>
            <th class="column-title">Price</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Instead of the serial number 1,2,3 etc  -  this is what is appearing   ${sn}

Comment: @mikefolu you may be trying this with a browser that does not yet support string literals that use the back tick character. Changing that part to old-school string concatenation of `...' + sn + '...` should take care of it.

Comment: @mikefolu or have you replaced the back ticks with single quotes? Does the code work on this page when you click the **Run code snippet** button?

Comment: It works when I changed to ' + sn + '   but I am using chrome

Comment: @mikefolu, Hmmm, strange ... Template strings should work on chrome since version 41: https://caniuse.com/template-literals